# Check if token from an email matches before allowing user to make database changes

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.4 to make an in-house app that does not have any authentication (out of my control). A user submits information, and an email is sent to a manager with the info and they can either accept/reject it by clicking on a button. If they click on the accept button a new window opens up where they can do stuff like change the user submitted information.

A token is generated and sent in the email so when the manager presses the `accept` button the token is sent along in the URL. How can I verify that the token is valid (matches what is saved in the database) before allowing them to make any updates or changes? Is possible to block access to the route so they cant even open the webpage if the token is invalid?

I would also appreciate other ideas on how to best protect the app without using authentication

Comment: You can add some middleware that checks the token. If the token is a mismatch then reject the request. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

Comment: So its as simple as retrieving the token from the database in `handle()` and checking it against the token in the request?